# Jquery function not being called on Page unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
                <input type="submit" name="Post" value="Post" class="btm-bg" />






 <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">  </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
$(function () {

    $('.option').hide();

    $('input[class="Tproperty"]').click(function () {

        $('.option').hide();

        if ($(this).val() == '2' ||  $(this).val() == '8') {
            $('#Display').show();
            $('#residential').hide();
            $('#amen').hide();
        }
        if ( $(this).val() == '5') {
            $('#Display').show();
            $('#residential').hide();
            $('#amen').hide();
            $('#xtrafac').hide();
            $('#parkings').hide();
            $('#rooms').hide();
            $('#bathrooms').hide();

        }
        else {
            $('#Display').show();
            $('#residential').show();
            $('#amen').show();
            $('#xtrafac').show();
            $('#parkings').show();
            $('#rooms').show();
            $('#bathrooms').show();

        }
    });
});
```

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    alert("hello");
    var sr = $("input[name = saleorrent]:checked").val();
    alert(sr);
    var mr = $("input[name = Monthlyrent]").val();
    alert(sr + mr);
    if (sr == "Rent" && mr == null  ) {
        alert("Enter monthly rent");
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

```
$(function () {

    $('.showes').hide();

    $('input[class="saleorrent"]').click(function () {

        $('.showes').hide();

        if ($(this).val() == 'Sale') {
            $('#optionsale').show();
            $('#sale').show();
            $('#rent').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#optionRent').show();
            $('#sale').hide();
            $('#rent').show();
        }
    });
});
```

function CheckNumeric(e) {

```
    if (window.event) // IE 
    {
        if ((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) & e.keyCode != 8) {
            event.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { // Fire Fox
        if ((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) & e.which != 8) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

```
$(function () {
    $("#City").change(function () {
        if ($("#City").val() != 0) {
            var ddlCityId = $(this).val();
            var subItems = "";
            $.getJSON("@Url.Action("ddlCities", "Listings")", { id: ddlCityId },
                    function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                            subItems += "<option value='" + item.Locality_Id + "'>" + item.Locality + "</option>"
                        });
                        $("#Locality").html(subItems)
                    });
        }
        else {
            alert("false");
        }
    });
});
```

I am using MVC 4.0 . I want an alert message if the field is left empty. But the thing is as soon as I click the submit button it reaches out to the server side and not executing the jquery code before unloading the page.

Comment: FYI, that isn't a jQuery function, it's a native JavaScript event.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - My apologies james. I have edited the question  but this either isn't working

Comment: `beforeunload` fires after a form submission as the form submission can be cancelled. You need to stop the form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`beforeunload` fires after a form submission as the form submission can be cancelled. You need to stop the form submission instead. e.g. like:

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    alert("hello");
    var sr = $("input[name = saleorrent]:checked").val();
    alert(sr);
    var mr = $("input[name = Monthlyrent]").val();
    alert(sr+ mr);
    if (sr == 'Rent' &&  mr == " ")
    {
        alert("Enter monthly rent");
       e.preventDefault();      // <<<<<< Stop the form submission
    }

});
```

**Notes:**

Always use prop('checked') with checkboxes.

```
var sr = $("input[name=saleorrent]").prop('checked');
```

Comment: Well this code is working but the thing is I haven't entered any value for rent but the radio button for Rent is checked and still its not showing alert message for "Enter monthly rent".

Comment: I was not trying to fix your form, just the specific issue you mentioned. If you post a JSFiddle I will correct the other issues for you. :)

Comment: PS. Use `prop('checked')` and not `val()` for checkboxes.

Comment: See update or at least post your full HTML and I will create the JSFiddle.

Comment: Ah. I should have specified the output HTML (from the browser) and not the MVC source code. Please note your question no longer matches your code, so you may get some flak (down-votes).

Comment: Hey I got it inside the if condition block. But the thing is its not stopping the navigation. I used "" without spaces in if condition for the Monthlyrent.